# How to execute a specific item in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a command executing a tripwire hook when it is thrown in the ground you summon a lighting bolt but it seems you can't add NBT tags in an execute command so how to specify the item I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot do it using execute only you must use scoreboard as in the following:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=item] Lightning 1 {Item:{id:"minecraft:tripwire_hook",Damage:0s,Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"Lightninger",Lore:[]}}}}
```

then

```
/execute @e[score_Lightning_min=1] ~ ~ ~ summon Lightning_Bolt
```

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft 1.13 merged NBT tags into the selector syntax, making this easy:

```
/execute as @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:tripwire_hook",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"\"Lightninger\"",Lore:[]}}}] run summon lightning_bolt
```