# How to test if 2 items are near each other in Minecraft 1.10.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I made a custom crafter in Minecraft 1.10.2. I want to obtain it by throwing a dropper and crafting table on the ground together. Everything is OK, but if I throw a dropper and a crafting table really far away from each other (crafting table 50 blocks away from dropper), it still runs. That's not ok. So, how to test if 2 item are nearby one to another in Minecraft?

Comment: Why are you in 1.10.2?

Comment: Fabian Röling i'm making map on that version

Comment: But why? Almost nobody plays it anymore and people will have to downgrade to play it, which involves creating a new launcher profile, choosing a different .minecraft folder (because downgrades in the same .minecraft folder are not supported and often cause issues), changing all controls, video and audio settings again and and so on, then later deleting all of that again. There's no downside to playing in 1.12.2 instead, it has all features of 1.10.2 and more, also a lot of bug fixes.

Comment: @FabianRöling that's ok with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you have a `testfor` command that tests if both a dropper and a crafting table are on the ground.

What I suggest you do is run an `execute` command at either of the two items, and test of the other item is nearby:

```
/execute @e[<firstItem>] ~ ~ ~ testfor @e[<secondItem>,r=<distance>]
```

As you can see, I added `r=` to test only for entities in a certain radius (if you need the items to be 3 blocks or closer to each other, type `r=3`, and so on.). You can then put the command into a command block and lead a comparator out of it that would execute the command for custom crafting.

Because you already had half the thing working, I figured out you already found out a method of testing for specific items. An example can be found [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304055/how-to-execute-a-specific-item-in-minecraft), just in case.

Comment: thanks you very much for fixing my bad english and helping my problem

Comment: I suggest not using `testfor` at all, you don't ever need it. Just use `execute`.

Comment: @FabianRöling How would that work?

Comment: @Quijibo it's work thanks you so much

Comment: `/execute at @e[type=item,bla=bla] at @e[type=item,limit=1,bla=bla] run say hi`

Comment: If you ever put a comparator on a command block with something other than a lamp behind it, I will haunt your house and eat all your cookies. ;)

Comment: @FabianRöling /execute at @e[type=item,bla=bla] at @e[type=item,limit=1,bla=bla] only works in 1.13+

Comment: Oh, right. But the concept is the same (and I forgot the distance before): `/execute @e[type,bla] ~ ~ ~ execute @e[type,r,bla] ~ ~ ~ say hi`

Comment: @ILikeFish Glad I could help :) Also, I should start putting lamps behind comparators. I like having my cookies not eaten.

Comment: @Quijibo but there're a few problem:I have a system testing if dropper and crafting table are throwed on the ground. Then 2 comparators and an AND gate get the redstone to the command you have gave me then a comparator will move the signal to some command block to summon the custom crafting table.When i throw dropper and craftng table near each other, it works but the redstones still got signal from the command block have your command to some summon command blocks and it only works once. I tried to put /scoreboards players reset <player> <objective> after all but it didn't work. What wrong?

Comment: @ILikeFish I think the problem is that you are using two command blocks that lead to an AND gate, when you don't actually need them. You can have just the command that I showed, because you don't need to test if there are these two items somewhere in the world if you are also testing if the items are right next to each other. So, you can remove the two command blocks that are just testing if the dropper and crafting table are thrown on the ground.

Comment: @Quijibo oh i've checked everything again and i found a mistake that i don't choose the correct command block for your command. Thanks for helping me :))