# How do i set a drop command to a specific item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I now have this:

```
/execute at @e[type=item,nbt={OnGround:1b}] run clone [pillar corner xyz] [pillar opposite corner xyz] ~ ~ ~
```

But I want to make it so that if you drop a spruce_fence it will go off.

Comment: I appreciate that you split up your project into individual problems, but have you tried looking at the wiki and other people's questions here? That would solve your problem much faster than waiting hours for an answer (and it's also expected from you before you ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can test for a specific item with

```
execute as @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:minecraft:your_item_here}}]
```

As shown in [this previous answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/355401/243753).

Comment: Item IDs are a `TAG_String`, so it's best practice to surround your ID with `"`quotation marks`"`. Like this: `id:"minecraft:stone"`